# Adding a column to table. Getting SYNTAX error but not sure why

Tags: mysql, sql, addition, alter

Not sure why these two lines aren't letting me add a column.

```
    ALTER TABLE people
    ADD COLUMN job_desc VARCHAR(15) BEFORE salary;
```

Comment: You should post the complete error message and the definition of people(don't expect us to search your previous questions) And do familiarise yoursefl with the manual  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html where it's clear before is not an option

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html), the syntax is:

> ADD [COLUMN] *col_name* *column_definition*
>           [FIRST | AFTER *col_name*]

You can use `FIRST` or `AFTER`, but not `BEFORE`. If you want to put it before a particular column, find the preceding column and put it `AFTER` that one. If you want to put it before the first column, use `FIRST`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AFTER` instead of before.

//e: Barmar was quicker :D